# Center of a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree

Given an unoriented tree with weightless edges with N vertices and N-1 edges and a number K find K nodes so that every node from a tree is within S distance of at least one of the K nodes. Also, S has to be the smallest possible S, so that if there were S' < S at least one node would be unreachable in S' steps.

I tried solving this problem, however, I feel that my supposed solution is not very fast.
My solution: 
set x=1
find nodes which are x distance from every node
let the node which has the most nodes in its distance be one of the K nodes.
recompute for every node whilst not counting already covered nodes.
do this till I find K number of K nodes. Then if every node is covered we are done else increase x.

Comment: sorry there was a mistake on my part, edited now

Comment: 1. Do a BFS from every node and record distances; 2. You would know the minimum distance to select K nodes.

Comment: To clarify - does every node need to be within distance $$K$$ of one of those nodes, including nodes that are one of the $$K$$ chosen nodes?

Comment: Well every node needs to be in distance S from atleast some node K.

Comment: I suppose a better clarification would be that the task is to find the minumum number S. So that i d be able to choose K number of nodes which "cover" the entire graph. and than output the nodes in K

Comment: The algorithm you're describing so far doesn't actually always find the smallest possible set of nodes. For example, consider a graph consisting of a central node, three nodes that each hang off that central node, where each of those hanging nodes in turn have one node each hanging off of them. Then the central node would have four nodes within a radius of 1 (itself, plus the three hanging off), but picking it is the wrong call. You'd be better off ignoring it and choosing the three nodes hanging off it as your set S.

Comment: Your solution is what is called "greedy".  It will tend to produce a reasonable approximation fairly quickly.  The problem itself that you are trying to solve sounds NP-complete to me.

Comment: @templatetypedef important thing is i am no looking for smallest set of nodes. I am given my allowed number of nodes K. Only thing i am worried about which has to be minimal is the distance S.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. Sorry, I misinterpreted the question!

Comment: I suggest a web search for "dynamic programming on trees"

Answer (score 1):

This problem is called p-center, and you can find several papers online about it such as [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25768634?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents). It is indeed NP for general graphs, but polynomial on trees, both weighted and unweighted.

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like a clustering problem. Try it with the [k-Means (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) algorithm where k equals to your K. Since you have a tree and all vertices are connected, you can use as distance measurement the distance/number of edges between your vertices.
When the algorithm converts you get the K nodes which should be found. Then you can determine S by iterating through all k clusters. There you calculate the maximum distance for every node in the cluster to the center node. And the overall max should be S.

Update: But actually I see that the k-means algorithm does not produce a global optimum, so this algorithm wouldn't also produce the best result ...

Answer (score 0):

You say N nodes and N-1 vertices so your graph is a tree. You are actually looking for a connected K-subset of nodes minimizing the longest edge.

A polynomial algorithm may be:
Sort all your edges increasing distance.
Then loop on edges:

- if none of the 2 nodes are in a group, create a new group.
- else if one node is in 1 existing goup, add the other to the group
- else both nodes are in 2 different groups, then fuse the groups

When a group reach K, break the loop and you have your connected K-subset.

Nevertheless, you have to note that your group can contain more than K nodes. You can imagine the problem of having 4 nodes, closed two by two. There would be no exact 3-subset solution of your problem.

Comment: Oh, I realized that I misunderstood the problem. Ok when you talk about "every node from a tree", it is the tree of the N initial nodes... My answer is off topic then.